# How can I merge two string lists?

Tags: python, string

I have now two lists

```
a = ['Redemption', 'The', 'II', 'Dark']
b = [912, 813, 230, 567]
```

I would like to have a result of,

```
c = 
Redemption 912  
The 813
II 230
Dark 567
```

The code below is what I have tried but the output is incorrect:

```
aa = [a[i] for i in range(10)]
bb = [str(b[j]) for j in range(10)]

for i in aa:
    for j in bb:
        c = i + ' ' + j
    print(c)
```

**Result is**

```
Redemption 567
The 567
II 567
Dark 567
```

Comment: Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip) `for x, y in zip(a, b):print(f'{x} {y}'})`

Comment: The most Pythonic way is to use [zip()][1]

  [1]: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a single for loop if you are matching elements on the same index, assuming the lists are the same length.

Try this:

```
a = ['Redemption', 'The', 'II', 'Dark']
b = [912, 813, 230, 567]

for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i],b[i])
```

Comment: This works, but it is uglier and slower than the pythonic solution of using `zip()`.

Comment: Thanks! A further question, how could the output be sorted in descending order by the b list? 
ie, 
Redemption 912  
The 813
Dark 567
II 230

Comment: @goxywood You can use zip() and sorted() to do that all in one line: c = sorted(zip(a, b), key=lambda z: z[1], reverse=True)